# how to make image slider in dojo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I've seen this image slider on the front page of http://www.ibm.com/us/en/ and I want to have one like that for my site. (After a timeout, the first image slides out of the screen, then the second image flies out after it, and then a new pair fly in).

I've seen that IBM uses Dojo not jQuery. Is this built in effect in dojo?

I have knowledge in javascript (but not any library like jQuery/dojo) and I can make it myself the hard-way. But I wanted to know first if there is anything built in to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image slider on the IBM.com front page is built using Dojo, but not a out-of-box component  of Dojo library. It's a customized component.

If you want to create image sliders using Dojo, take a look at existing out-of-box components in DojoX library (`dojox.image`). [`dojox.image.SlideShow`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/image/SlideShow.html#dojox-image-slideshow) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be better off with [dojox.widget.Rotator](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/widget/Rotator.html) or even [dojox.widget.AutoRotator](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/widget/AutoRotator.html).